# Resource Monitor (resmon) in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

In Windows Server 2008 R2's Resource Monitor, is there a way to set the scale of the various graphs to be constant values instead of variable based on data?

It seems to me that the utility of a graph is to get a quick overview glance at the values those graphs are showing.

So if I look at the CPU graph and the line is up near the top, I can know immediately that something is using all my CPU and go investigate what. I don't really care if the CPU is jumping between .01% and 2%.

Or if the network usage monitor is up near the top, I will know that all my bandwidth is being used up, and go figure out what.

But the way things are now, the graphs are meaningless because the scales constantly shift. If you look at the network usage graph in one second it might have a scale out of 100kbps, and the next second have a scale based on 1mbps!

So... is there a registry key or something that will peg the scale of these graphs to logical maximums?

(the graph on the right hand side of the screenshot below):
[alt text http://media.win7articles.com/windows-7-resource-monitor.jpg](http://media.win7articles.com/windows-7-resource-monitor.jpg)

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to this as well - anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately the resource monitor is sort of a "quick and dirty" method of viewing performance data, and is basically preconfigured by Microsoft.

If you want less pretty but more configurable graphs, you can create custom collector sets in Performance Monitor (run `perfmon.msc`) and with this you can control the scaling of various monitors in the graph.